# How would one calculate percent error between two ratios

Tags: math, scientific-computing

Let's say I have a 1:1 ratio and a 5:1 ratio which could also be interpreted as a 1:5 ratio. the fact that both of these ratios are valid but one is 5 while the other is 0.2 is the problem, because if we plug this into the percent error formula (|E−T|/|T|) we get both 80% and 400%. which would be correct? what are the rules for this? Right now I just need to figure out how to do this mathematically, this isn't a problem with the code.

Comment: "a 5:1 ratio which could also be interpreted as a 1:5 ratio" -- how so? The odds for an event are not the same as the odds against an event. A 5:1 ratio isn't the same thing as a 1:5 ratio. "what are the rules for this?" -- to know what the ratio *means* in a particular context? "this isn't a problem with the code." -- then maybe [mathematics.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: John, this is with empirical formula where you have a ratio of the elements, to 1:5 and 5:1 would be equivalent, only because the ratio we are comparing against in this case is 1:1, this is an edge case.

Comment: But still a ratio of 1 carbon to 5 nitrogen isn't the same of as a ration of 5 carbon to 1 nitrogen. You need context to give things like `1:5` meaning. The fact that `1:5` in one context might mean the same as `5:1` in a related (but in some sense opposite) context is interesting but doesn't make the ratios the same. There is no mathematical way to infer context from the numbers themselves. Perhaps there are conventions in chemistry that would help disambiguate `1:1`. [chemistry.se] might be a good site to ask in.